# Logger and FileHandler are executed on caller's method thread?

Tags: java, android, logging, timber, filehandler

On Android I'm using Timber with java.util.logging.Logger and FileHandler to write the logs on files.
I have debugged the code and seems it write the log on file on the same caller's method thread.
Do you know why ? In this way, it can be a problem to call the log methods on the ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know why ? In this way, it can be a problem to call the log methods on the ui thread.

The logging API relies on the [Handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) to abstract away the details.  Currently there is no AsyncFileHandler included in the JDK so you have to make one or find a 3rd party lib to provide one. E.G. [Tomcat JULI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/package-summary.html).

You can build one from the source code included here: [Using java.util.logger with a separate thread to write on file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406632/using-java-util-logger-with-a-separate-thread-to-write-on-file)